# Bootstrap add up more than 12

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to pull data from a database into columns, but the total columns add up to more than 12. The columns have different heights. This messes up the grid. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">   
   <div class="col-md-3"> ... </div>
   <div class="col-md-3"> ... </div>
   <div class="col-md-3"> ... </div>
   <div class="col-md-3"> ... </div>
   <div class="col-md-3"> ... </div>
   <div class="col-md-3"> ... </div>
   <div class="col-md-3"> ... </div>
   <div class="col-md-3"> ... </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What language is your program written in? PHP?

Comment: Yes, PHP. I'm working on a Wordpress theme actually, but it's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1** is to add a standard height to all of your `<div>`.  So you could create a class like `.div-200px`.

Change your `<div class="col-md-3">` to `<div class="div-200px col-md-3">`

Edit your CSS:

```
 .div-200px {
     height: 200px; 
}
```

**Option 2** is to create a foreach loop and add a new `<div class="row">` for every 4 products.

```
<div class="container">
    <?php $count = 0;
    foreach($data as $item){
        if(is_int($count/4)){ ?>
            <div class="row">
        <?php } ?>
            <div class="col-md-3"> <?=$item?> </div>
        if($count>0 AND is_int($count/4)){ ?>
            </div>
        <?php } 
        $count++;
    } ?>
</div>
```

That's not the prettiest thing but it should work.

Comment: Thank you, I was hopeing for a CSS trick that doesn't involve a fixed height.

Comment: The first option will not work for the use cases where the height is not known.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option with CSS, add a "item" class to your col-md-3 divs and give it the following css:

```
.item:nth-child(4n+1){
    clear:left
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works very well.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should not solve this with bootstrap grid system at all. Just use `<table>` tag and stop caring about a number of columns. Responsiveness shouldn't suffer

Comment: This really depends on what the content is.  A table may or may not have the styling OP is looking for.  It is a good suggestion though it's not necessarily an answer to this question.